# MySQL RESTRICT and NO ACTION

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, cascade

What's the difference in a MySQL FK between `RESTRICT` and `NO ACTION`? From the doc they seem exactly the same. Is this the case? If so, why have both?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

From MySQL Documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

> Some database systems have deferred
>   checks, and `NO ACTION` is a deferred
>   check. In MySQL, foreign key
>   constraints are checked immediately,
>   so `NO ACTION` is the same as `RESTRICT`.

Answer (score 22):

It is to comply with standard SQL syntax. Like the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) says: (emphasis mine)

> NO ACTION: **A keyword from standard SQL**. In MySQL, equivalent to RESTRICT. The MySQL Server rejects the delete or update operation for the parent table if there is a related foreign key value in the referenced table. **Some database systems have deferred checks, and NO ACTION is a deferred check. In MySQL, foreign key constraints are checked immediately, so NO ACTION is the same as RESTRICT.**

Answer (score 18):

They are identical in MySQL.

In the SQL 2003 standard there are 5 different referential actions:

```
CASCADE
RESTRICT
NO ACTION
SET NULL
SET DEFAULT
```

The difference between `NO ACTION` and `RESTRICT` is that according to the standard, `NO ACTION` is deferred while `RESTRICT` acts immediately.