# Exact Meaning of MySQL's Foreign Key 'on delete restrict' Clause

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have two MySQL tables: `collections` and `privacy_level`.
I define them with a **foreign key** relationship as such:

```
CREATE TABLE collections (
  coll_id smallint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNSIGNED,
  name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  privacy tinyint NOT NULL UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY(coll_id),
  INDEX(privacy),
  FOREIGN KEY fk_priv (privacy) REFERENCES privacy_level (level) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB;  

 CREATE TABLE privacy_level (
   level tinyint NOT NULL UNSIGNED,
   name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (level)
 ) ENGINE InnoDB;
```

My question is about the `ON DELETE RESTRICT` clause and I couldn't derive the answer from the online manual or a google search.

Does this mean that I can **never** delete a row from `privacy_level`?
Or, does it mean that I **can't** delete a row from `privacy_level` **if** a row from `collections.privacy` has a value that is the same as a value in `privacy_level.level`?

That is, if `privacy_level` has `level = 2`, `name = 'top secret'` but no entry in collections.Privacy has `privacy = 2`, can I delete the `level = 2`, `name = 'top secret'` entry? Or is it forbidden on a column wide basis?

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

`ON DELETE RESTRICT` means you **can't** delete a given **parent row** if a **child row exists** that references the value for that parent row.  If the parent row has no referencing child rows, then you can delete that parent row.

`ON DELETE RESTRICT` is pretty much *superfluous* syntax, because this is the default behavior for a foreign key anyway.

Comment: Do you mean `ON DELETE RESTRICT` is the same as `ON DELETE NO ACTION`?

Comment: @Shafizadeh, read http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/on-delete-restrict-vs-on-delete-no-action

Comment: @Bill, that article says NO ACTION is the same as RESTRICT in MySQL, and it refers [back to SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809954/mysql-restrict-and-no-action) to back their statement...

Comment: @Code4R7 cf."Specifying RESTRICT (or NO ACTION) is the same as omitting the ON DELETE or ON UPDATE clause." https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 7):

Also you can use `ON DELETE CASCADE`, that means when you delete the parent all the children will be removed automatically, this is useful when you have a table  associated with another that contains some parameters or settings.

Comment: which one is the parent and which one is the child row?  Is it the one referencing another the child or the other way around?

Comment: If you have two tables, users, and user_settings, the users' table is the parent, and the user settings table is the child. So, when you delete a user, automatically will delete the settings related to the deleted user.

Comment: While it does make sense that the 'users' table is the parent table, technically there is nothing saying that it can't be the other way around. It just depends on which column references what column. The referencing column is the child, the referenced column the parent.