# Prevent delete if object in some collection

Tags: sqlalchemy, many-to-many

In SQLAlchemy is it possible to prevent (or specifically raise a custom Exception) the deletion of an object that is part of a collection in a many-to-many relationship.

For example below I have a `Party` and `Person`. Any `Party` can have many `Persons` and any `Person` can go to many `Parties`.

If a `Person` is recorded as going to one or more `Parties` I want to prohibit that `Person` from being deleted.

```
party_person_ass_table = db.Table('party_person', db.Model.metadata,
                     db.Column('party_id', db.ForeignKey('party.id'), primary_key=True),
                     db.Column('person_id', db.ForeignKey('person.id'), primary_key=True))

class Party(db.Model):
    ... 
    people = db.relationship('Person', secondary=party_person_ass_table, back_populates='parties')

class Person(db.Model):
    ... 
    parties = db.relationship('Party', secondary=party_person_ass_table, back_populates='people')
```

Reading the docs it seems cascade deleting from the secondary table is automatically set (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html). I wonder if a solution to generate an `IntegrityError` would be to add a `nullable=False` to the `person_id` column in the secondary association table and then somehow prevent a cascade delete from impacting the secondary table?

Comment: I’d just make `party_person_ass_table.person_id` [ON DELETE RESTRICT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8073114/6560549).

Comment: @SuperShoot sounds sensible so I changed to `db.Column('person_id', db.ForeignKey('person.id', ondelete='RESTRICT'), primary_key=True))` but it had no effect. I am using SQLite3 and am executing `PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON`. I destroyed and recreated my DB, so not sure if I am missing something else?

Comment: I couldn't get the above to work. Instead, I tested putting `viewonly=True` inside `parties=db.relationship(..)`. Now when a `Person` is deleted which exists in the secondary table an `IntegrityError ForeignKey constraint` exception is raised, which I think is because the delete cascade is not followed and therefore creates the break.

Comment: As a further comment to why your solution above didn't work is becuase I think that SQLalchemy instructs the secondary table rows deletion (as an automatic cascade) before the physical object delete event. Therefore `ondelete='RESTRICT'` has no effect since those objects have been previously and individually deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding the tag `viewonly=True` to:

```
parties = db.relationship('Party', secondary=party_person_ass_table, back_populates='people', viewonly=True)
```

decouples `Person` from the `party_person_ass_table` and when modified it does not automatically delete the row in the association table, which breaks database integrity.

This is also why the commented 'ON DELETE RESTRICT' fails because it isnt an inherent cascade, but SQLAlchemy specifically deletes these rows as part of its function so these hooks aren't called in the usual way.