# Dropping column with foreign key Laravel error: General error: 1025 Error on rename

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, database-migration

I've created a table using migration like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('despatch_discrepancies',  function($table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('pick_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('pick_id')->references('id')->on('picks');
        $table->integer('pick_detail_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('pick_detail_id')->references('id')->on('pick_details');
        $table->integer('original_qty')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('shipped_qty')->unsigned();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('despatch_discrepancies');
}
```

I need to change this table and drop the foreign key reference & column `pick_detail_id` and add a new varchar column called `sku` after `pick_id` column.

So, I've created another migration, which looks like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('despatch_discrepancies', function($table)
    {
        $table->dropForeign('pick_detail_id');
        $table->dropColumn('pick_detail_id');
        $table->string('sku', 20)->after('pick_id');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('despatch_discrepancies', function($table)
    {
        $table->integer('pick_detail_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('pick_detail_id')->references('id')->on('pick_details');
        $table->dropColumn('sku');
    });
}
```

When I run this migration, I get the following error:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of
>   './dev_iwms_reboot/despatch_discrepancies' to
>   './dev_iwms_reboot/#sql2-67c-17c464' (errno: 152) (SQL: alter table
>   `despatch_discrepancies` drop foreign key pick_detail_id)
>
> [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of
>   './dev_iwms_reboot/despatch_discrepancies' to
>   './dev_iwms_reboot/#sql2-67c-17c464' (errno: 152)

When I try to reverse this migration by running `php artisan migrate:rollback` command, I get a `Rolled back` message, but it's not actually doing anything in the database.

Any idea what might be wrong? How do you drop a column that has a foreign key reference?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

It turns out; when you create a foreign key like this:

```
$table->integer('pick_detail_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('pick_detail_id')->references('id')->on('pick_details');
```

Laravel uniquely names the foreign key reference like this:

```
<table_name>_<foreign_table_name>_<column_name>_foreign
despatch_discrepancies_pick_detail_id_foreign (in my case)
```

Therefore, when you want to drop a column with foreign key reference, you have to do it like this:

```
$table->dropForeign('despatch_discrepancies_pick_detail_id_foreign');
$table->dropColumn('pick_detail_id');
```

### Update:

Laravel 4.2+ introduces a new naming convention:

```
<table_name>_<column_name>_foreign
```

### Update:

Larave > 8.x introduces a new function

```
dropConstrainedForeignId('pick_detail_id');
```

This will delete the column as well as the foreign key of the column

Comment: Does not work in Laravel 4.2.  <foreign_table_name> is not part of the key name.  It works with just <table_name>_<column_name>_foreign.

Comment: I used it in laravel 4.2 and still do, it works for me.

Comment: The `<table_name>_<column_name>_foreign` convention still seems to work for 5.1

Comment: Apparently, after dropping the constraint on the relationship, you have to drop the column too. i think the documentation should have included that too because one can easily assume dropForeign will also delete the column. thanks for the sharing.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#dropping-columns

Comment: If anyone was wondering, indexes that MySQL automatically creates for foreign keys are dropped when the columns are. No need to drop them manually with `$table->dropIndex('column_name')`.

Comment: Also don't forget prefixes. Laravel desn't add those automatically either.

Comment: Larave > 8.x introduces a new function 1+

Answer (score 267):

You can use this:

```
Schema::table('despatch_discrepancies', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropForeign(['pick_detail_id']);
    $table->dropColumn('pick_detail_id');
});
```

If you take a peak at dropForeign source, it will build the foreign key index name for you if you pass the column name as an array.

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me; however, this one did. Cheers.

Comment: The accepted answer works too: you have to use the right index name convention. But this is the problem with that answer too: you have to remember the naming scheme for indexes, while this solution do it automatically! I always used the other way, and always complained about how unpractical it was. Now I'm immediately switching to this solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: Awesome trick. I've been doing it the long way like a sucker. Laravel could really use some help on the docs. I may take up the challenge...

Comment: Worked for me in Laravel 5.0.  Thanks so much, Alex!

Comment: Worked like a charm in Laravel 5.2.

Comment: This is a neat trick. Way friendlier than remembering the foreign key naming convention (which might change in the future). Like @ronin1184 said, works perfectly in Laravel 5.2

Comment: This answer also works in Laravel 4.2, and it is much easier to remember. Thanks!

Comment: Works well in Laravel 5.3 too 

Comment: Works on 5.4! Checked the documentation and this appears since 5.1: "you may pass an array value which will automatically use the conventional constraint name when dropping". https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Comment: Working flawlessly on Laravel 5.7!

Comment: This only works if you created the foreign keys with Laravel to begin with. In my case the foreign keys had been created long before Laravel entered the picture and across multiple databases which had auto-generated different foreign key names. I'm correcting this by explicitly dropping and then re-creating the FKs with new names so I can easily run FK related migrations.

Comment: If anyone was wondering, indexes that MySQL automatically creates for foreign keys are dropped when the columns are. No need to drop them manually with `$table->dropIndex('column_name')`.

Comment: if you did not manually set the key of the foreign key,, this is the right answer..

Answer (score 34):

I had multiple foreign keys in my table and then I had to remove foreign key constraints one by one by passing column name as index of the array in down method:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('offices', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('country_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('country_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('countries')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->unsignedInteger('stateprovince_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('stateprovince_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('stateprovince')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->unsignedInteger('city_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('city_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('cities')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('offices', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign(['country_id']);
        $table->dropForeign(['stateprovince_id']);
        $table->dropForeign(['city_id']);
        $table->dropColumn(['country_id','stateprovince_id','city_id']);
    });
}
```

Using below statement does not work

```
$table->dropForeign(['country_id','stateprovince_id','city_id']);
```

Because dropForeign does not consider them seperate columns that we want to remove. So we have to drop them one by one.

Comment: Thanks my friend, adding the column name in an array works for me.

Comment: If anyone was wondering, indexes that MySQL automatically creates for foreign keys are dropped when the columns are. No need to drop them manually with `$table->dropIndex('column_name')`.

Comment: ty, i wanted `Schema::table('offices', function (Blueprint $table) {}` so bad...

Comment: for some reason laravel doesn't prefix table name and postfix 'foreign' in dropForeign. so i think it should be: `$table->dropForeign(['offices_country_id_foreign']);`

Answer (score 10):

The key (for me) to solving this was to make sure that the $table->dropForeign() command was being passed the right relationship name, not necessarily the column name. You do **not** want to pass the column name, as would be much more intuitive IMHO.

What worked for me was:

```
$table->dropForeign('local_table_foreign_id_foreign');
$table->column('foreign_id');
```

So the string I passed to dropForeign() that worked for me was in the format of:

**[local table]**_**[foreign key field]**_foreign

If you have access to a tool like Sequel Pro or Navicat, being able to visualize those will be very helpful.

Comment: This works fine, I just found it to be less intuitive than surrounding the table in brackets as @Alex suggested.

Answer (score 9):

Something that occurred to me was that I didn't know where to put the `Schema::table` block.

Later I discovered that the key is on the SQL error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1217 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (SQL: drop table if exists `lu_benefits_categories`)
```

So the `Schema::table` block needs to go in the `down()` function of the `lu_benefits_categories` migration and before the `Schema::dropIfExists` line:

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('table', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('table_category_id_foreign');
        $table->dropColumn('category_id');
    });
    Schema::dropIfExists('lu_benefits_categories');
}
```

After that, the `php artisan migrate:refresh` or `php artisan migrate:reset` will do the trick.

Answer (score 7):

on laravel 8 use **dropConstrainedForeignId**
(https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/34806)

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddAddressFieldsInEventTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        
        Schema::table('events', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigInteger('address_id')->nullable();

            $table->foreign('address_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('addresses')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('events', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropConstrainedForeignId('address_id');
            $table->dropColumn('address_id');
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Laravel > 8.x you can use the following code to add/remove foreign keys. You will need to drop the foreign key before dropping the column, as otherwise, the foreign key could cause the error your encountering.

### Add foreign key

```
 $table->foreignId('pick_id')->constrained('picks')->cascadeOnUpdate()
->cascadeOnDelete();
```

### Drop foreign key

```
  $table->dropConstrainedForeignId('pick_id');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can disable relation id first

```
Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
```