# Laravel 5.2 drop foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Good day,

I am trying to drop a foreign key in a Laravel 5.2 migration previously implemented like this:

EDIT: The creation of the id in the table (before using foreign key on it) was:

```
$table->integer('agent_rights_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

The foreign key:

```
Schema::table('agents', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->foreign('agent_rights_id')->references('id')->on('agent_rights');
    });
```

My drop looks like this:

```
 Schema::table('agents', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->dropForeign('agents_agent_rights_id_foreign');
        $table->dropColumn('agent_rights_id');
    });
```

I found out, that one must take the "real" index name and not the label - this I have already thought of in the previous snippet (as a reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27175808/dropping-column-with-foreign-key-laravel-error-general-error-1025-error-on-ren)).

But this gives me the errors:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                                                                                                          
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of './{name}/agents' to './{name}/#sql2-2a6-1d8' (errno: 152) (SQL: alter table `agents` drop foreign key `agents_agent_rights_id_foreign`)  



[PDOException]                                                                                                                                  
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of './{name}/agents' to './{name}/#sql2-2a6-1d8' (errno: 152)
```

Researching this brings up no real solutions, only bug messages from MySQL...

**Question:** Do you guys anything about this, or what was wrong with my snippet?

Comment: I did what is told in this question before I created this post. This is not the same question, because I already did what is told there.

Comment: You are missing something because i ran the same in my project and it works fine. Anyway i remove duplicate and reopen it.
I also double check your script again.
See the Laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations.

Comment: you can also pass an array value which will automatically use the conventional constraint name when dropping like `$table->dropForeign(['agent_rights_id']);`

Comment: @Manish I tried that, but sadly the same errors... Was I expected to add something special to the column before it was made a foreign key except unsigned()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Mentenyia This is compulsory for using `unsigned()` before creating Foreign key constraint. Please read the link https://laravel3.veliovgroup.com/docs/database/schema#foreign-keys .

> Note: The field referenced in the foreign key is very likely an auto
>   increment and therefore automatically an unsigned integer. Please make
>   sure to create the foreign key field with unsigned() as both fields
>   have to be the exact same type, the engine on both tables has to be
>   set to InnoDB, and the referenced table must be created before the
>   table with the foreign key.

So you should have to create like this:

```
$table->integer('agent_rights_id')->unsigned(); // Always create column before creating Foreign key constraint otherwise this will also give error.
$table->foreign('agent_rights_id')->references('id')->on('agent_rights');
```

After when you will be going to delete Foreign key No issue/ error will arise.

> For droping Indexing Use this method **table-name_column-name_index-type**

```
$table->dropForeign('agents_agent_rights_id_foreign');
```

Comment: I still have the error when doing this, also when not using nullable() after unsigned()... But I will set up the whole database again from scratch to test it. I will answer then :)

Comment: It was the nullable() after unsigned() which did the trouble. Thank you for your help :)