# Laravel drop foreign Key in Migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.6

I want to create a Migration which shall drop a table. I created the Migration like this:

```
Schema::table('devices', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('client_id')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

And now I try to drop it like this:

```
    Schema::table('devices', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('devices_client_id_foreign');
        $table->drop('devices');
    });
```

But I get following error:

> ```
> In Connection.php line 664:
>
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'devices_client_id_foreign'; check that column/key exists (SQL:
> ```
>
> alter table `devices` drop foreign key `devices_client_id_foreign`)
>
> ```
> In PDOStatement.php line 144:
>
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'devices_client_id_foreign'; check that column/key exists
>
>
> In PDOStatement.php line 142:
>
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'devices_client_id_foreign'; check that column/key exists
> ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to disable foreign key checks before you drop the table then enable them again after like this:

```
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');
Schema::dropIfExists('devices');
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');
```

Comment: If creating a migration that adds and drops particular columns this wont work. for example if you are adding a column to the users table this command drops the entire users table which could be catastrophic. better to use @laurazel8 response in the down function

Answer (score 32):

You can use this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30177480/8513937

Pass to *dropForeign* the column name as array. Internally, Laravel drops the associated foreign key.

```
$table->dropForeign(['client_id']);
```

Comment: This works when you didn't give it a different FKs name that Laravel sets by default.

Answer (score 7):

Try this ways...

```
  public function down()
 {
    Schema::dropIfExists('devices');
 }

//Or this
  public function down(){
    Schema::table('devices', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign(['client_id']);
        $table->dropColumn('client_id');
        $table->drop('devices');
    });
  }
```

Comment: There is a foreign key I can't drop it that easily

Answer (score -1):

Just drop the whole table ([documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#renaming-and-dropping-tables)):

```
Schema::drop('devices');
```

Comment: Hi there is a foreign key Client_id so I cant drop it that easily

Comment: `Integrity constraint violation: 1217 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (SQL: drop table `devices`)`

Comment: Are there foreign keys in other tables that reference the `devices` table?

Comment: why drop the whole table in down method when we are not creating table in up method?

Comment: You can't drop the whole table while it has a foreign key.