# MySQL duplicate key in table

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-sql

I have an error with the following SQL query and I'm not sure how to fix it. The error message is:

> "Error Code: 1022. Can't write; duplicate key in table
>   **'t_course_catalog'**"

Here is the query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TrainingPlan`.`T_Course_Catalog` (
 `CC_ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `ID_Catalog_Level` INT NOT NULL,
 `Catalog_Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 `ID_Delivery_Method` INT NOT NULL,
 `Created_Date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `Created_By` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
 `Modified_Date` TIMESTAMP NULL,
 `Modified_By` VARCHAR(8) NULL,
 `Deleted` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 PRIMARY KEY (`CC_ID`),
 INDEX `fk_cl_idx` (`ID_Catalog_Level` ASC),
 INDEX `fk_dm_idx` (`ID_Delivery_Method` ASC),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_cl`
   FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Catalog_Level`)
   REFERENCES `TrainingPlan`.`T_Catalog_Level` (`CL_ID`)
   ON DELETE NO ACTION
   ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_dm`
   FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Delivery_Method`)
   REFERENCES `TrainingPlan`.`T_Delivery_Method` (`DM_ID`)
   ON DELETE NO ACTION
   ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

It should be no problem to reference the foreign keys because the reference table exists.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error 1022 - Can't write; duplicate key in table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056786/error-1022-cant-write-duplicate-key-in-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming your constraints, they are probably duplicated somewhere in your database.

Example :

```
fk_cl becomes fk_course_catalog_cl
fk_dm become  fk_course_catalog_dm
```

Or w/e alternative name you want it to be.