# Can't write; duplicate key in table 'UserSessions' Even pk name changed

Tags: mysql

I want to create two table `AdminSessions` and `UserSessions` to store the client session data. Both of them have a pk named `sessionKey` with the properties of `PK`, `NN`, `UQ`. When I try to do a forward engineering, I encounter `Can't write; duplicate key in table 'UserSessions'`. After reading [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18057522/2828227), I try to change the name of the pks to `sessionKeya` and `sessionKeyb` but it does not work.

How to solve this error?

**Error Message**

```
ERROR: Error 1022: Can't write; duplicate key in table 'UserSessions'
```

[image]
[image]

**SQL**

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CodeSpace`.`UserSessions` (
      `sessionKey` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
      `userId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `lastAccessTime` DATETIME NULL,
      `ip` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `expiryTime` DATETIME NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`sessionKey`),
      UNIQUE INDEX `userId_UNIQUE` (`userId` ASC),
      UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`sessionKey` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_UserSession_1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`userId`)
        REFERENCES `CodeSpace`.`Users` (`id`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Comment: The problem is not with the columnname of the primary key, it is very likely the name of the foreign key, `fk_UserSession_1`, you probably use this name somewhere else. Rename it (or look for the duplicate with e.g. `select * from information_schema.innodb_sys_foreign where id like '%fk_UserSession_1';` and rename it there, because its name fits to this table)