# Can't write; duplicate key in table 'emails' in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql

I was doing forward engineering, I got this error as ERROR: Error 1022: Can't write; duplicate key in table 'emails', I tried to change name constraints but same error was getting, Can you help me to solve this error
thanks

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1022: Can't write; duplicate key in table 'emails'
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `mydb`.`Emails`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Emails` (
          `EId` INT NOT NULL,
          `Type` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          `Email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          INDEX `ProfileId_idx` (`EId` ASC),
          CONSTRAINT `ProfileId`
            FOREIGN KEY (`EId`)
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`personprofile` (`ProfileId`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 7 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Comment: Check again if `profileid` constraint exists in database by using the answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056786/error-1022-cant-write-duplicate-key-in-table)

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`personprofile` (
  `ProfileId` INT NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `LastName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Birthdate` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `MartialStatus` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Gender` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Height` INT NULL,
  `ValidIdTypes` VARCHAR(45) NULL,......
  `
yes exists

Comment: So that is the problem right! Try changing the constraint names.

Comment: I've also had this problem with MySQL 5.7.26, but being sure I didn't have any other existing key with the same name. There had previously been a key with the same name, but it had been deleted. I solved it by exporting the schema, deleting it and importing it again. I imagine it will be some MySQL problem that does not empty its caches well, despite having restarted the service even, or something similar.