# What's the meaning of RESTRICT in Foreign Keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

There is 4 cases: *(For example I'm talking about `ON DELETE`)*

- **`CASCADE`**: the referencing rows will be deleted automatically along with the referenced ones.
- **`SET NULL`**: the value of referencing record will be set to `NULL` automatically along with the referenced ones.
- **`NO ACTION`**: There will not be any change in the the referencing rows when the referenced ones are deleted.
- **`RESTRICT`**: { I cannot understand its concept }

I read the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) several times for that, but still I cannot understand what `RESTRICT` does. May you please someone explain it by an example?

I read somewhere `NO ACTION` and `RESTRICT` are the same in MySQL. Is that true?

Comment: From the reference you quoted:  `if you have defined a RESTRICT type constraint, and there is a child row with several parent rows, InnoDB does not permit the deletion of any of those parent rows.`  What is your interpretation of that?

Comment: @DanBracuk the MySQL manual is well known for being not the easiest language form to understand....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

RESTRICT: It will not allow deleting this (parent) record without deleting dependent records (records which are referring foreign key from this)

For example, with these tables:

- `parent`:

  ```
  ID  NAME
  1   AAAA
  2   BBBBB
  ```
- `child`:

  ```
  ID  PARENT_ID
  1   1
  2   1
  3   2
  ```

We can expect the following behaviors:

- ```sql
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ```

  If we delete `AAA` from parent it will: **delete** entries 1 and 2 in child
- ```sql
  ON DELETE SET NULL
  ```

  If we delete `AAA` from parent it will: set the column PARENT_ID to **null** for entries 1 and 2 in child
- ```sql
  ON DELETE SET DEFAULT
  ```

  If we delete `AAA` from parent it will: set the column PARENT_ID to their **default value** for entries 1 and 2 in child
- ```sql
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ```

  If we delete `AAA` from parent it will: allow deleting and have **no action** on entries in child
- ```sql
  ON DELETE RESTRICT
  ```

  We can't delete `AAA` from parent without updating or deleting the entries 1 and 2 in child first

Comment: I guess all cases *(`CASCADE`, `SET NULL`, `NO ACTION`)* also *will not allow to delete parent record without deleting dependent records*.

Comment: no on delete cascade when we delete record in parent record it will delete related entries on child table

Comment: @Stack added all 4 definition with example because it will help others as well

Comment: Hi @MaheshMadushanka
What you mean by saying set to the default value:

ON DELETE SET DEFAULT:
set the column PARENT_ID to their default value for entries 1 and 2 in the child.

Comment:  I know this question from the past.
But the past for the future.

Comment: ON DELETE NO ACTION will not allow the deletion of the parent. This is standard SQL. (I am afraid the above answer is erroneous.)

Answer (score 3):

RESTRICT: Rejects the delete or update operation for the parent table. Specifying RESTRICT (or NO ACTION) is the same as omitting the ON DELETE or ON UPDATE clause.

NO ACTION: A keyword from standard SQL. In MySQL, equivalent to RESTRICT. The MySQL Server rejects the delete or update operation for the parent table if there is a related foreign key value in the referenced table. Some database systems have deferred checks, and NO ACTION is a deferred check. In MySQL, foreign key constraints are checked immediately, so NO ACTION is the same as RESTRICT.

Comment: do you have an reference for this answer, Amar?

Comment: @Martin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809954/mysql-restrict-and-no-action#5810022

Comment: you can test this like this,                                            

                                                                                                                              [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
    [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [ON DELETE reference_option]
    [ON UPDATE reference_option]

reference_option:
    RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION

Answer (score 2):

RESTRICT will not allow to delete or update parent record if record existing in child table

Answer (score -1):

you can test this like this,

```
                                                                                                                          [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
[index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
[ON DELETE reference_option]
[ON UPDATE reference_option]
```

reference_option:
    RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION